# c++ const mysqlpp::String ambiguous error

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie to c++ and have just got c++ querying an sql database with mysql++.h

The SQL query itself works, and I can print out results.

```
char *token;
Query query = conn.query();
query << "SELECT title, description FROM mydb.mytable LIMIT 2";
StoreQueryResult ares = query.store();

for (size_t i = 0; i < ares.num_rows(); i++) {
    cout << "Title: " << ares[i]["title"] << " - Description: " << ares[i]["description"] << endl;
    const char delim[] = "; \t";

    //Error when I add this line
    //token = strtok( ares[i]["description"] , delim);
    //rest of strtok code which works with normal strings, but not mysqlstring
    ...
}
```

The key issue being me trying to parse the description into words with the line

```
   token = strtok( ares[i]["description"] , delim);
```

I get the error

```
error: conversion from ‘const mysqlpp::String’ to ‘char*’ is ambiguous
```

So my understanding is that strtok takes a char* and that conn is returning a const mysqlpp::String, which makes sense I guess. But then how do I use the mysqlpp::String with other normal functions that take a char* ?

I was looking over [here](https://tangentsoft.com/mysqlpp/doc/html/refman/classmysqlpp_1_1String.html) to get some tips, but getting stuck.

I've tried things like converting with..

```
ares[i]["description"].c_str();
```

which gives invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’

```
char * c = ares[i]["description"].c_str()
```

which gives similar error.

So I'm a bit lost at this point, how to use mysqlpp::String elsewhere, what's the best way to use this with functions that take char* or std::string?

What is the ambiguous bit getting at ?

Comment: the contents of the pointer `.c_str()` returns should not be modified. But `strtok` does this actually. You can use `strdup` to get a modifiable copy.

Comment: Rather than using `strtok`, look up the MySQL string type and see if it has some methods you can use.

Comment: And then `strdup` requires freeing the memory.  Better to not use `strtok` regardless of the type of string, since it has other flaws, such as relying on a static buffer.

Comment: `mysqlpp::String` defines multiple implicit conversion operations, which are leading to the ambiguity. But more importantly, `mysqlpp::String` is an **immutable** type. It doesn't expose any functionality that allows you to mutate its data, only to assign new data via `assign()` and `operator=`.  But `strtok()` wants to mutate the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok` will alter the string you pass in that it inserts string termination character `0x0` after each token. So you need a `char*`, but `c_str` returns a `const char*`.

If you want to use `strtok`, you will need to get a copy of the `const char*` returned by `c_str()`. The probably easiest way is to use `strdup`:

```
char* c = strdup(ares[i]["description"].c_str());
token = strtok(c, delim);
...
free(c);
```

Or:

```
std::string s = ares[i]["description"].c_str();
char* c = s.data(); // or &s[0] prior to C++17...
token = strtok(c, delim);
```

Comment: Thanks, really useful explanations, both work fine. So both essentially have to copy the data one way or another ? But is there an alternative not using strtok which could use mysqlpp::String directly (just thinking about performance as it's going to do a lot of parsing)?